# Word for "easy to dismiss"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, vocabulary

I know that there is an adjective with that meaning. I just cannot think of it or find it online. I'd be very grateful if someone pointed out a word that means "easy to dismiss" or something similar.

It intend to use it in a sentence similar to this:  *"His criticism is ______."*

Comment: Which sense of *dismiss* are you referring to? Can you provide a sentence to show the usage in context?

Comment: A little more context of what you're looking for might help. The word that popped into my mind was specious, but I'm not confident that is the sort of word you desire.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with his criticism?

Comment: ***flimsy***, ***baseless*** or ***unsubstantiated***?

Comment: 'Unmemorable' and 'disregardable' exist.

Answer (score 4):

**Trivial** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trivial)

> *adjective* 1. Of little value or importance
>   *"huge fines were imposed for trivial offences"*

"Trivial" would satisfy your sentence. Keep in mind the difference between something *seeming* trivial and actually *being* trivial.

Answer (score 3):

> His criticism is *inconsequential*.

**Inconsequential**

> :  of no significance :  unimportant

"Inconsequential." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 28 June 2016.

Answer (score 1):

You can say

> His criticism is ***negligible***.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/negligible) says that

> An amount or effect that is *negligible* is ***so small that it is not worth considering or worrying about***.
>
> - e.g. The cost is huge, the effect ***negligible***. (Times, Sunday Times, 2011)

Comment: The default reading here is that 'he' doesn't criticise to an appreciable degree.

Answer (score 1):

"His criticism was **uncalled for**."
"His criticism is **superfluous**."

Or with feeling,
"His criticism aggravated me."

Or on the slang side.
"His criticism **sucked**"

Comment: If the criticism _aggravated me_ or it _sucked_ then clearly it wasn't easy to dismiss.

Comment: @SteveBird. Agreed, but it depends on the attitude of the person saying it, for example: if it sucked, or if it aggravated him,  the person saying it would dismiss it as useless and therefore it would be easy to dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

### nugatory

> adjective
> of no value or importance.
>
> *"a nugatory and pointless observation"*

Definition via [Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.google.com/search?q=nugatory+meaning&oq=nuga&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0i433l2j46i433j0.2733j0j7&client=ms-android-hmd-rev2&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives that might be more specific. It could be illogical, contradictory, a fallacy, an oxymoron or self-contradictory, an ad hominem attack, a distraction or diversion, vacuous, non-falsifiable, sophistry...